# How to handle Privilege Escalation in Spring application

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, owasp

We have an application with 3 different user roles as User, Author & Admin. Each access role is having different set of menus and screens.

Issue is even though Menu item is hidden if we capture the admin URL and past it in user login it is opening the page. All action on the page will not work but still we are planning to restrict the page opening as well.

Only way I could see how we can handle is write a condition in each action to validate the access before opening the page. But with this approach we should touch many files, is there any best way to handle this situation.

Our application is written using Spring MVC framework.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You asked:

> But with this approach we should touch many files, is there any best
>   way to handle this situation.

From Spring MVC `HandlerInterceptor` [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html):

> "Applications can register any number of existing or custom
>   interceptors for certain groups of handlers, ***to add common
>   preprocessing behavior without needing to modify each handler
>   implementation.***"

What you may do:

- Write a custom `HandlerInterceptor` which should extend
  `HandlerInterceptorAdapter`.
- Override the `boolean preHandle()` method. This method is invoked just before the handler is invoked. So you can check access of logged in user (maybe from session). You can write a custom response from within this method.
- Register the interceptor in your `dispatcher-servlet.xml`.

For example:

```
public class AuthInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
                             HttpServletResponse response,
                             Object handler) throws Exception {

        String uri = request.getRequestURI();
        User user = (User) request.getSession().getAttribute("foo"); //for example

        if (...) {        //check access to this uri, if access fails
            response.sendRedirect("/to/some/url");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

And register this `HandlerInterceptor` to `dispatcher-servlet.xml`:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="your.package.AuthInterceptor"/>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

You can configure this interceptor to be more url-specific. See [Spring Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-config-interceptors) and [Spring javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html).